# How to have social media icons above a picture, in line?

Tags: html, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWrs.jpg)

I would like to know how I could have 3 social media icons, on top of each picture and to the left, but in line with the image. Below is my code.

```css
body {
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

#downloadbutton{
 width:127px;
 height:48px;
 text-align: center;
 /* text-indent:-9999px; */
 border:none;
 margin-top:20px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#downloadbuttonhover:hover{
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #b40000;
 opacity:0.9;
}


.buttonDownload{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 25px;
  
 background-color: #b30000;
 color: white;
  
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 text-align: center;
 text-indent: 15px;
}

.buttonDownload:hover {
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;
}

.buttonDownload:before, .buttonDownload:after {
 content: ' ';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 top: 52%;
}

/* Download box shape  */
.buttonDownload:before {
 width: 10px;
 height: 2px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 2px 2px;
}

/* Download arrow shape */
.buttonDownload:after {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 3px;
 margin-top: -7px;
  
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-top-color: inherit;
 
 animation: downloadArrow 2s linear infinite;
 animation-play-state: paused;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:before {
 border-color: #b30000;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:after {
 border-top-color: #b30000;
 animation-play-state: running;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.divWithBtn {
 display: inline-block;
}

.divWithBtn a{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</br>
 <span class="textformat1"><center><b>Albums</b></span></center>
</br>



<div id="sharebar">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"{count} data-url="www.tekmillion.com" data-text="TekMillion - Download Albums http://www.tekmillion.com/albums.html" data-via="tekmill">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<hr>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.tekmillion.com/albums.html" data-layout="button_count"></div>
</div>
<script>var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script src="//w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>



<center>
 <div class="clear">
  <div class="divWithBtn">
   <img src="socialmedia/twitterwhiteandblack.png" alt="twitterwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="socialmedia/googlepluswhiteandblack.png" alt="googlepluswhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="socialmedia/facebookwhiteandblack.png" alt="facebookwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover"      width="200" height="200">
  <a href="LONDON%202%20TURKEY%20VOL.1.zip">
   <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
  </div>
 <div class="divWithBtn">
  <img src="images/LONDON%20TO%20TURKEY%20VOLUME%202%20(FRONT%20COVER).jpg" alt="LONDON%20TO%20TURKEY%20VOLUME%202%20(FRONT  %20COVER)" width="200" height="200" border:none;>
   <a href="LONDON%202%20TURKEY%20VOL.2.zip">
  <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
 </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
   <img src="images/Love%20%26%20Hate%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover).JPG" alt="Love%20%26%20Hate%20Volume.1%20(Front     %20Cover)" width="200" height="200">
  <a href="LOVE%20%26%20HATE%20VOL.1.zip">
 <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
  </div>
 <div class="divWithBtn">
  <img src="images/Gurbet%20Eli%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover).JPG" alt="Gurbet%20Eli%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover)" width="200"   height="200">
 <a href="GURBET%20ELI%20VOL.1.zip">
  <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</center>
</br>
</div>
```

You can see the album pictures and links at the link: http://tekmillion.com/albums.html

Thanks.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Put all three icon outside the first div `divWithBtn`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to work

Comment: And where are that three social icon on live link. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your icon outside in new div with class `.divWithBtn`.

**Note:** Here i have set decrease height and width to display it proper.

```css
body {
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

#downloadbutton{
 width:127px;
 height:48px;
 text-align: center;
 /* text-indent:-9999px; */
 border:none;
 margin-top:20px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#downloadbuttonhover:hover{
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #b40000;
 opacity:0.9;
}


.buttonDownload{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 25px;
  
 background-color: #b30000;
 color: white;
  
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 text-align: center;
 text-indent: 15px;
}

.buttonDownload:hover {
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;
}

.buttonDownload:before, .buttonDownload:after {
 content: ' ';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 top: 52%;
}

/* Download box shape  */
.buttonDownload:before {
 width: 10px;
 height: 2px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 2px 2px;
}

/* Download arrow shape */
.buttonDownload:after {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 3px;
 margin-top: -7px;
  
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-top-color: inherit;
 
 animation: downloadArrow 2s linear infinite;
 animation-play-state: paused;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:before {
 border-color: #b30000;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:after {
 border-top-color: #b30000;
 animation-play-state: running;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.divWithBtn {
 display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.divWithBtn a{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.socialIcon > a{
  display:inline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
</br>
 <span class="textformat1"><center><b>Albums</b></span></center>
</br>



<div id="sharebar">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"{count} data-url="www.tekmillion.com" data-text="TekMillion - Download Albums http://www.tekmillion.com/albums.html" data-via="tekmill">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<hr>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.tekmillion.com/albums.html" data-layout="button_count"></div>
</div>
<script>var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script src="//w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>



<center>
 <div class="clear">
        <div class="divWithBtn">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover"      width="100" height="100">
  <a href="LONDON%202%20TURKEY%20VOL.1.zip">
   <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
          <div class="socialIcon">
            <a href="link">
           <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="twitterwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30"></a>
            <a href="link">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="googlepluswhiteandblack" width="30" height="30"></a>
            <a href="link">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="facebookwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30"></a>
        </div> 
  </div>
 <div class="divWithBtn">
  <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="LONDON%20TO%20TURKEY%20VOLUME%202%20(FRONT  %20COVER)" width="100" height="100" border:none;>
   <a href="LONDON%202%20TURKEY%20VOL.2.zip">
  <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
        <div class="socialIcon">
           <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="twitterwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="googlepluswhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="facebookwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
        </div>  
 </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="Love%20%26%20Hate%20Volume.1%20(Front     %20Cover)" width="100" height="100">
  <a href="LOVE%20%26%20HATE%20VOL.1.zip">
 <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
          <div class="socialIcon">
           <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="twitterwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="googlepluswhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="facebookwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
        </div> 
  </div>
 <div class="divWithBtn">
  <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/london%20To%20Turkey%20-%20Front%20Cover.jpg" alt="Gurbet%20Eli%20Volume.1%20(Front%20Cover)" width="100"   height="100">
 <a href="GURBET%20ELI%20VOL.1.zip">
  <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50"></a>
      <div class="socialIcon">
           <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="twitterwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="googlepluswhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
   <img src="http://tekmillion.com/images/Twitter.png" alt="facebookwhiteandblack" width="30" height="30">
        </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
</center>
</br>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

As per your requirement put your icon new div like in code i have put it in `socialIcon` div. And put it below download button.

You can put image inside anchor tag.

And give following css make your link line.

```
.socialIcon > a{
  display:inline;
  }
```

Comment: I want to have a set of 3 social media icons under the download button under each picture or ontop of each picture.

Comment: And can I add a href? to each social media icon? with them still being inline and under each download button?

Comment: There seems to be an issue in the code, I have applied the example to my own code but it seems to turn out like this: http://tekmillion.com/albums.html

Comment: Why you gave `width:100px` to `.divWithBtn`. I have added here temporary. and give social image proper path.

Comment: So what do i need to change?

Comment: remove width from `.divWithBtn` and give proper image path to social icon.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to approve/accept the answer.